# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am getting the error of conversion failed in my codebehind. My code is below:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand((tempUsertype == "0" ? "Select * from tbl_students" : "Select * from tbl_students where Id in (Select Id from tbl_students where NgoId=@NgoId)"), conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NgoId", Convert.ToString(Session["User"]));
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ddlStudent.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Id"].ToString();
    ddlStudent.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["first_name"].ToString();
    ddlStudent.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    ddlStudent.SelectedIndex = 0;

    if (Session["UserType"] == "1" || Session["UserType"] == "2")
    {
        ddlStudent.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ddlStudent.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "--Select NGO--", Value = "0" });
        ddlStudent.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value  to data type int.

What changes has to be done here?

Comment: As an aside, this is strange: `ddlStudent.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Id"].ToString()`. Because you are getting the string `"Id"`  which you already know at that point.

Comment: It seems likely that whatever is in `Session["User"]` is not an integer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, so what to do in this case ??

Comment: Is the NgoId an int or a string? You're passing it as string cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NgoId", Convert.ToString(Session["User"]));

Comment: @jadarnel27: yes it is not an integer,,

Comment: what is the exact value when you use the debugger when hitting this line 
`Session["User"]` please provide all relevant information.. also can you truly verify that there is data being populated in this line `da.Fill(ds);` also show us what the command text looks like meaning which Select Statement is it trying to run..

Comment: @MethodMan: It doesn't goes in that.

Comment: then perhaps you need to change the way that you are trying to build your sql  command.. break it down into 2 separate select statements with in an if statement.. the problem appears to be in this code 
`using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand((tempUsertype == "0" ? "Select * from tbl_students" : "Select * from tbl_students where Id in (Select Id from tbl_students where NgoId=@NgoId)"), conn))` use the debugger please

Comment: @MethodMan: Yes but it is not going inside that..

Comment: you have some serious issues going on here @Nadeem and based on what you are stating vs what code you are showing.. I would seriously suggest refactoring the code... stepping through it using the debugger.. telling us exactly what line of code it's failing on ... and showing all relevant code.. what I have suggested in regards to breaking out the sql will work if in fact that's where the disconnect is happening..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75215/discussion-between-nadeem-and-methodman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `NgoId` is an int but you're assigning a string. So this might fix it:

```
var p = new SqlParameter("@NgoId", SqlDbType.int).Value = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(Session["User"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Edit: since you have commented that the session stores the username but the `NgoId` is an int-column you have three options:

1. change the session to store the user-id `int` instead of the name
2. change the column to store the username
3. select the user-id from the table where the username is stored.

I would either prefer the first  or the last option.

This works  if you also prefer the last approach:

```
string sql = "Select * from tbl_students";
if(tempUsertype != "0")
{
    sql = @"Select s.* 
            from tbl_students s 
            where s.NgoId in (Select u.NgoId 
                              from tbl_User u 
                              where u.username = @Username)";
}
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    var p = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.varchar);
    p.Value = Convert.ToString(Session["User"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToString(Session["User"]);
```

This will coerce the NgoId parameter to the SQL Server int data type.

Comment: getting error as `The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))`